# google sheet to laravel

Tags: php, laravel, google-sheets-api

I have built a CRM that manage leads

I have a table called leads, and in the controller in `index()` method 
, I made a request to google API to get the data from my sheet table.

now what's is happen, that in every page refresh i use `updateOrCreate()` 
 to update the table 
and show it in the leads index view with `dataTable()`

my problem is as I mentioned above, that every page refresh it calling the method to google API,
and it's a performance issue that gets to me in the long run when it is thousand of records

and my question is if there is a way to listen to the sheet table if made changes
 (edit or added row)
and updated only in this situation

I have thought about to do another table to the sheet data but I need it updated somehow

I need guidelines for how and if I can to do so,
or there is a better way to it.

```
  public function index(Request $request, Lead $lead) 
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=../att-sheets-b5343f28dd39.json');
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);

    $driveService = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

    // List Files
    // $response = $driveService->files->listFiles();

    // Set File ID and get the contents of your Google Sheet
    $fileID = '1okqjGbGDnbzJbXDwZ1A6RHJ3LddyL6fGMZWnq88xUiw';
    $response = $driveService->files->export($fileID, 'text/csv', array(
          'alt' => 'media'));
    $content = $response->getBody()->getContents();

    // Create CSV from String
    $csv = Reader::createFromString($content, 'r');
    $csv->setHeaderOffset(0);
    $records = $csv->getRecords();

    // Create an Empty Array and Loop through the Records
    $newarray = array();
    foreach ($records as $value) {
        $newarray[] = $value;
    }


    foreach ($newarray as $data) {
        $matchThese = array('email' => $data['your-email']);



        Lead::updateOrCreate($matchThese,[
            'user_name'    => 'admin',
            'name'       => $data['your-name'],
            'tel'        => $data['your-tel'],
            'source'     => 'Google sheets',
            'sheet_date' => $data['date'].', '.$data['time'],
        ])->save();
    }




    $user = User::all();


    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $data = Lead::where('deleted', '!=' , '1')->orWhereNull('deleted')->latest()->get();
        return Datatables::of($data)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->addColumn('action', function($lead){
                    $btnEdit = '';
                    $btnDel = '';
                    if(auth()->user()->can('update', $lead))
                    {
                        $btnEdit = '<a href="/leads/'.$lead->id.'/edit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary edit" id="'.$lead->id.'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit</a>';
                    }
                    if(auth()->user()->can('delete', $lead))
                    {
                        $btnDel = '<a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger delete" id="'.$lead->id.'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Delete</a>';
                    }
                    $btnShow = '<a href="/leads/'.$lead->id.'" class="btn btn-sm btn-success show">View</a>';
                    $btn = $btnEdit . $btnDel . $btnShow;
                    return $btn;
                })
                ->addColumn('checkbox', function($lead)
                {
                    $checkbox = '';
                    if(auth()->user()->can('delete', $lead))
                    {
                        $checkbox = '<input type="checkbox" name="leads_checkbox[]" class="leads_checkbox" value="'.$lead->id.'">';
                        return $checkbox;
                    }
                })
                ->rawColumns(['action','checkbox'])
                ->make(true);
    }

    return view('leads.index', compact(
        ['user', 'lead'])
    );
}
```

thanks for the help!!!

Comment: You can achieve this by creating laravel command and hit it using cron.

Comment: Can you explain it more about cron it's the first time i heared about this

Comment: Please go through this link for custom command https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan or for better example you can follow https://dev.to/enkaypeter/making-a-custom-laravel-artisan-command-in-laravel-54 and run the command using cron.

Comment: Consider using Apps Script instead of PHP https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet This gives you the option to use trigger which detect changes in your sheet automatically  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable